# SSMS Ctrl+Tab Page Thumbnail Preview Add-on?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is there a SQL Server Management studio add-on/plug-in that will enhance the tab switching dialog box when Ctrl+Tab is used to switch tabs to provide a thumbnail image of the tab?

When we use Ctrl+Tab to switch tabs we see the list of tabs open. When we switch tabs in Visual Studio we get a small thumb nail preview screen of the tab along with the tab names. It would be great if there was an add-on that we could install to provide an image in addition to the file names.

Thx,
Catto